# Small C applications that are vulnerable to fuzzing(and have the source code available)

Tags: c, fuzzing

Could anyone please point me in the direction of a small c application that is known to be vulnerable to fuzzing(I will be fuzzing it using zzuf) that has the source code available and is easily installed on Ubuntu. Many Thanks

Comment: You're looking for an existing application with a known vulnerability ?

Comment: @ydroneaud: for example, any application that *used* to have a known vulnerability, just before the check-in that fixed it.

Comment: @ydroneaud: A small application(could be an old version) that is known to have a vulnerability which is open source and can easily be installed on ubuntu. I will apply zzuf to it. This is surprisingly hard to find on the net. Thanks

Comment: You could start by looking at software crash reported here http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/zzuf/bugs

Comment: well, looked there. Supervisor wasn't too happy with that suggestion(too big) and I'm not sure that it has available source code

Comment: @ydroneaud: I should explain that I need source code because I'll be doing some unit testing on it too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [libtiff 3.9.4](http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/tiff-3.9.4.tar.gz) (specifically `tiff_getimage.c`) which is according to [CVE-2012-1173](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-1173) vulnerable to multiple integer overflows, allowing remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via a crafted tile size in a TIFF file.